# Do I need Schengen Visa for transit in Dusseldorf, flying in from CGK-Abu Dhabi-Dus-JFK?

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm flying from CGK to JFK with connection in AUH and DUS. All with Air Berlin, with flight from CGK-AUH-DUS operated by Etihad.
Do I need to have Schengen visa for transit in DUS?

Comment: You haven't provided your citizenship(s) ot help us answer this

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you don't need a transit visa; see

https://www.dus.com/en/flights/transferring

> Departure airport outside the Schengen Area/Destination outside the
>   Schengen Area:
>
> ```
> No border control in Düsseldorf
> No transit visa required
> ```

2) There is a caveat that this rule applies to citizens of most but not all countries. There is an exception for several countries, whose citizens need a transit visa; see http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html

> Nationals of the following countries are required to be in possession
>   of an airport transit visa when passing through the international
>   transit area of airports in Germany:
>
> AFGHANISTAN, BANGLADESH, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO, ERITREA,
>   ETHIOPIA, GHANA, INDIA, IRAN, IRAQ, JORDAN ** (please see below),
>   LEBANON, MYANMAR, MALI, NIGERIA, PAKISTAN, SOMALIA, SRI LANKA, SUDAN,
>   SOUTH SUDAN, SYRIA, TURKEY

However, if citizens of the countries have a US visa they are exempt from the requirement of having an airport transit visa. (Since you are flying to JFK, I assume that you either have a US visa or you are a US resident/citizen.)

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted?